# How to validate a school email domain with php

Tags: php, html, css, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a school email ending in .ac.uk in php. I want to be able to check if the email submitted in the form has ended in .ac.uk in PHP

My PHP code:

```
if (empty ($_POST["uni_email"])) {
$emailErr2 = "University email is required";
} else {
  $uemail = $_POST["uni_email"];
  if ( !filter_var($uemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $emailErr3 = "Invalid email format";
   echo $emailErr3;
    
}
if (!preg_match('/ac.uk$/', $email)) {

  $emailErr3 = "Invalid university email format";
  echo $emailErr3;

}
```

I've seen ways using the checkdnsrr() function to check the domain but I'm not sure if that's the correct way as .ac.uk is not a domain and I want to ensure that it checks out for the .ac.uk after the domain. So a valid email would be bob@email.ac.uk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be something like this

demo : http://codepad.org/7PsanZIO

```
<?php 
$postEmail = 'user@university.ac.uk'; // as $_POST["uni_email"]
if (empty ($postEmail)) {
    $emailErr2 = "University email is required";
} else {
    $uemail = $postEmail;
    if ( !filter_var($uemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $emailErr3 = "Invalid email format";
     echo $emailErr3;
    }
}

if (substr(trim($postEmail), -6) === '.ac.uk') {
  echo 'email is correct';
} else {
  $emailErr3 = "Invalid university email format";
  echo $emailErr3;
}
?>
```

Comment: there is an improvement in the validation section `substr(trim($postEmail), -6) === '.ac.uk'`

Comment: the solution has a result of email is correct everytime regardless of the email, perhaps check what happens when the input is wronf

Comment: I just updated it, you can check back now http://codepad.org/7PsanZIO

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that last preg_match, you can do it in non-regex way:

```php
if(!endsWith($email, '.ac.uk'))
{
   // here handle your error, email doesn't end with .ac.uk.
   $emailErr3 = "Invalid university email format";
   echo $emailErr3;
}

function endsWith( $haystack, $needle ) {
    $length = strlen( $needle );
    if( !$length ) {
        return true;
    }
    return substr( $haystack, -$length ) === $needle;
}
```

Comment: could you explain the endsWith() function please

Comment: This method gets last $length characters from input string and compares them with $needle (in this case .ac.uk). If $length is false (in this example it means string length == 0, then it returns true (every string ends with nothing).